# Getting One row back despite Nulls/ None and Duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have a query that is close to what I want but not exactly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, 
                Ifnull(p.last_name, '--')         last_name, 
                Ifnull(p.first_name, '--')        first_name, 
                Ifnull(p.city, '--')              city, 
                Ifnull(p.state, '--')             state, 
                Ifnull(e.full_name, '--')         full_name, 
                Ifnull(o.current_step, '--')      current_step, 
                Ifnull(o.current_step_date, '--') current_step_date
FROM   prospect AS p 
       JOIN opportunity AS o 
         ON o.prospect_id = p.id 
       JOIN employee AS e 
         ON p.id_ofproducer = e.id 
WHERE  p.id = 1234
```

I am hoping to get the row from P back

Note:  If there is more than one o or e  record use the MAX ID,   IF there is none use "--"

Comment: If there could be no matching rows in `opportunity` or `employee` you need to use `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `left join` to handle the case where there are no records.  And, you need to find the maximum for the `o` and `e` records.  Actually, you shouldn't have a problem with the `e` records, because you are joining on the id.  Here is one way to formulate the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, 
                Ifnull(p.last_name, '--')         last_name, 
                Ifnull(p.first_name, '--')        first_name, 
                Ifnull(p.city, '--')              city, 
                Ifnull(p.state, '--')             state, 
                Ifnull(e.full_name, '--')         full_name, 
                Ifnull(o.current_step, '--')      current_step, 
                Ifnull(o.current_step_date, '--') current_step_date
FROM   prospect AS p 
       left JOIN opportunity AS o 
         ON o.prospect_id = p.id and
            o.id = (select id from opportunity o2 where o2.prospect_id = p.id order by id desc limit 1)
       left JOIN employee AS e 
         ON p.id_ofproducer = e.id
WHERE  p.id = 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.id, 
       Ifnull(p.last_name, '--')         last_name, 
       Ifnull(p.first_name, '--')        first_name, 
       Ifnull(p.city, '--')              city, 
       Ifnull(p.state, '--')             state, 
       Ifnull(e.full_name, '--')         full_name, 
       Ifnull(o.current_step, '--')      current_step, 
       Ifnull(o.current_step_date, '--') current_step_date
FROM   prospect AS p 
       JOIN opportunity AS o 
         ON o.prospect_id = p.id 
       JOIN employee AS e 
         ON p.id_ofproducer = e.id 
WHERE  p.id = 1234
ORDER BY o.prospect_id DESC, e.id DESC
LIMIT 1
```